# Reduce file size when merging gpx files to GeoJSON file with GDAL ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

Is it possible to reduce the file size of a geojson file with ogr2ogr?

I use following code in Mac Terminal to merge multiple gpx files to a GeoJSON file:

```
OGR2OGR_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/3.2/Programs/ogr2ogr

# Merge gpx files to geojson file

for file in $SCRIPT_DIR/input/*.gpx; do $OGR2OGR_PATH $SCRIPT_DIR/output/mergedgpxfiles.geojson -append "${file}" tracks -fieldTypeToString DateTime; done
```

I have read that there is following precision option but I dont know how to use it:

```
-lco COORDINATE_PRECISION=2
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you've done your appending, just convert the final file as

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" -lco COORDINATE_PRECISION=3 squashed.json \
        mergedgpxfiles.geojson
```

(change the value of COORDINATE_PRECISION to whatever suits you).

Comment: Thank you Jose. I have now done it with simplify (see my answer). Do you know if this two methods do the same?

Comment: They're slightly different. `simplify` simplifies the geometry, so depending on the tolerance, you may remove e.g. vertices in a polygon, whereas `COORDINATE_PRECISION` merely changes the number of digits of each coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

I have now done it with simplify:

```
OGR2OGR_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/3.2/Programs/ogr2ogr

# Merge gpx files to geojson file and simplify

for file in $SCRIPT_DIR/input/*.gpx; do $OGR2OGR_PATH -simplify 0.00001 -f "GeoJSON" $SCRIPT_DIR/output/mergedgpxfiles.geojson -append "${file}" tracks -fieldTypeToString DateTime; done
```